# Displaying Uploaded HEIC Images

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing a RESTful API where I display the images that users have uploaded onto AWS S3. The client wants to allow HEIC images, but there is currently [no support](https://caniuse.com/heif) for `.heic` and `.heif` file extensions on all browsers.

I have tried using the [heic-convert](https://github.com/catdad-experiments/heic-convert) library to convert the HEIC images to JPEG before uploading them onto AWS S3, but it's taking too long to convert a single image and that would affect user experience.

Was wondering if there are any other solutions to this?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, you will have to convert the image to something that browsers support in order to display it there.  There isn't any way to avoid that.

Comment: I agree with @jfriend00 . What you could do is use an ascyncronic call to upload the image or even to convert it after uploaded. That way the frontend doesn't have to wait for it, and it just happens in the background.